# numpy.nan weird behaviour in hashed object

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I am experiencing a weird behaviour when using numpy.nan that I can't understand.
Here is a minimal example:

```
from numpy import nan

def _bool3key(x):
  """
  Defines the keys used to order the list.
  The only allowed values are True, False, 1,0 and numpy.nan.
  """ 
  return _bool3key.__logic_sort__[x]
_bool3key.__logic_sort__ = {0:-1, nan:0 , 1:1}

def and3(*args):
   return min(*args,key=_bool3key)


def f(x):
  """long function that produces in output a vector containing only 0, nan and 1s.
  pass #
```

Sometimes the and3 function fails, despite in the vector returned by f(x) there are only 0, nan, or 1 values: the reason is that nan is not of type numpy.nan...

For example `v = f(x)` produced a vector `[nan,nan]`. However if I try to type:
`v[0] is nan` I get `False` (which is what causes and3 not to work); the weird thing though is that `v[1] is nan` is `True`.

What is causing this behaviour? How can I correctly use a nan value in my `and3` function??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use

```
_bool3key.__logic_sort__ = {0:-1, nan:0 , 1:1}
```

then one problem you might run into is that `float('nan')` is not recognized as the same key as `np.nan`:

```
In [17]: _bool3key(float('nan'))
KeyError: nan
```

Here is a workaround:

```
def _bool3key(x, logic_sort={0: -1, 1: 1}):
    """
    Defines the keys used to order the list.
    The only allowed values are True, False, 1,0 and nan.
    """
    return 0 if np.isnan(x) else logic_sort[x]
```

Also, attribute lookups are slower than local variable lookups, so 
you'll get slightly better performance defining `logic_sort` as a default parameter than by making it a function attribute. You don't have to define it outside of the function, and it is a little easier to read too.

Comment: Thanks! I figured that the behaviour was due to nan (thanks to the other answer and google), I really appreciated the workaround though!

Comment: Note that this change to `_bool3key()` alters the results for `inf` and `-inf` (before would raise `KeyError`, now gets `0`).

Comment: thank Brian, in f(x) I have checks to validate the content of the output, so that is not an issue (although in genereal it can be an issue)

Comment: but I realized that using isnan might be more appropriate :)

Comment: @BrianCain: Thanks Brian, I've changed `_bool3key` to make it live up to its docstring.

Answer (score 5):

`nan` should not be used as an index for a `dict` because it does not successfully compare with itself.

```
>>> float('nan') == float('nan')
False
>>> numpy.nan == numpy.nan
False
```

However, `nan` can be detected using [`math.isnan()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.isnan):

```
>>> math.isnan(numpy.nan)
True
```

Comment: Even worse, inside a dict it might work if it is the same nan (i.e. identity check succeeds)